# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/gb/myapp/dist/MyApplication.app

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

**Environment:**

Python 3.8

Pyqt5

Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.6

I am trying to compile my python program in Mac OS application. I get this error message when I open the app:

```
(base) gb@MacBookGB % open dist/MyApplication.app                           
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/gb/myapp/dist/MyApplication.app.
```

I checked that files can be executed:

```
ld -la dist/
drwxr-xr-x@   4 gb  staff   128 26 aoû 20:27 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 223 gb  staff  7136 26 aoû 20:44 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 gb  staff  6148 26 aoû 21:04 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x@   3 gb  staff    96 26 aoû 20:18 MyApplication.app

ld -la dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/Mac OS/
total 7016
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 gauthierbtz  staff      128 26 aoû 20:18 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 gauthierbtz  staff      224 26 aoû 20:18 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 gauthierbtz  staff    30048 26 aoû 20:18 PhoneBot_small
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 gauthierbtz  staff  3557260 26 aoû 20:18 python
```

So I searched everywhere on the web to find solution but none worked.
As I know Qt5 can make issue when compiling, I made a search and found your article:
[https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/deployment-pyinstaller.html](link url)

I decide to compile your python code shown in this article.

```
import sys
import random
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton,
                               QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PySide2.QtCore import Slot, Qt

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "你好，世界", "Hei maailma",
            "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]

        self.button = QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Connecting the signal
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)

    @Slot()
    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then I run the command:

```
pyinstaller --name="MyApplication" --windowed MyApp.py
```

And I get exact same issue :

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/gb/myapp/dist/MyApplication.app.
```

I wonder if anyone already faced this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The -10810 error message seems to be a catch-all for errors in the executable file inside the app.  For example, I have an app called Hello.app, and inside Hello.app/Contents/MacOS is a single executable script named Hello with two lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e "display dialog \"Hello, world!\""
```

When I issue the command:

```
open Hello.app
```

or double-click the folder icon in Finder.  I see the expected dialog box:

[image: Hello World Dialog]

However, when I introduce a syntax error:

```
osascript -e "display dialog "Hello, world!\""
```

the open command fails with the error message:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /full/path/name/of/Hello.app
```

To find the real error message, execute the program inside your app directly from the command line.  In my case, the command is:

```
Hello.app/Contents/MacOS/Hello
```

and the much more informative error message is:

```
./Hello: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

Of course, I have no idea what the actual error in your program is, but I hope this helps you find it!